# Getting Different values of VARIANT in VC++

Tags: active-directory, ldap, c++

I am **querying** my Active Directory From **c++**. I have successfully bind the IADs object with the server and Also I am able to retrieve user information. I am using VARIANT data type to retrieve the objects. Most of the object are BSTR strings. But attributes like **badPWDCount, pwdLastSet,logonCount** are not. Hence I am not able to retrieve those values. Please help me with this.

VARIANT var;
hr=testIAD->Get(query,&vari);
if(hr==0)
{
    printf(%S\n\n", V_BSTR(&vari)); 
}

Here I don't know how to use VARIANT to print data types other than BSTR.

Answer (score 0):

[`VARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a member named `vt` which indicates the value type it currently contains. For instance if `vt` is set to `VT_UNKNOWN` the variant contains a pointer to an IUnknown interface which can be set or retrieved using the `punkVal` member.

```
VARIANT v;
GetValueAsVariant(&v);
if(v.vt == VT_UNKNOWN)
{
    IUnknown *i = vt.punkVal;

    // ... do something ...

    i->Release();
}
```

There is a [list of variant types available on the MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)